# Switch Statement won't output;

Tags: java, switch-statement

My code would not output the switch statement do I need to use a different statement or condition? Every thing in till the switch statement works perfectly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NewClass {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        Scanner user= new Scanner(System.in);
        int hours;
        double biWeekly,payrate,weekly;
        String payPeriod;
        //Variables 

        System.out.print("Do you get paid weekly or bi weekly?:");
        payPeriod=user.nextLine();
        System.out.print("How many hours did you work ths week?:");
        hours=user.nextInt();
        System.out.print("How much is your pay rate?:");
        payrate=user.nextInt();
        //the code stops here and wont output the rest

        biWeekly=(hours*2)*payrate;
        weekly=hours*payrate;

        switch(payPeriod){
           case "weekly":
               System.out.println("Your weekly pay is $"+weekly+" Without tax reductions");
               break;
           case "biweekly":
               System.out.println("Your bi-weekly pay is $"+biWeekly+" without tax reductions");
               break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Step by step debugging is your friend.

Comment: add a `default` statement to print and see what the value is

Comment: Have you tried printing out payPeriod before the switch statement, and/or calling `payPeriod.trim()`?

Comment: Throw in a default case and print payPeriod to see what it actually is

Comment: What is your input? Did you try `payPeriod.toLowerCase()`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It works fine. Remember that it will go into the case statement only if payPeriod String is exactly as "weekly" or "biweekly", no space, no caps, etc.